# train data in nlp for extracting skills using LSTM but train and validation accuracy are not as expected

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, lstm, word-embedding

[I have manually created this data as mentioned in the document where 1 is skill and 0 is not_skill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTcfE.png)

this is my LSTM network

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size,100,input_length=max_len))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(256))
model.add(Dense(128,activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(64,activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(32,activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

[I dont understand why is there None below the model. Is it affecting models performance or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGDXK.png)

```
y=pd.get_dummies(d['Skill_NotSkill'])
xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

model.fit(xtrain,ytrain,epochs=20,batch_size=64,verbose=1,validation_data=(xtest,ytest))
```

the training accuracy is fluctuating and validation accuracy is constant.

[image]

Can anyone please help in training the model and point out if there are any issues in my code.
Also for extracting skills am I following right steps.

Comment: Try using Relu or LeakyRelu activation function in your dense layers except for your last dense layer.

Comment: I have posted the output relu is responding worse

Comment: Now I've looked into your data and realized your output is not 2 dimensional but your last dense layer returns a 2-dimensional output. The problem might be because of that can you try to use your last dense layer with 1 dim output.

Comment: But since I want to extract skills from the data I will have to use 2 in the last dense right. Also I am not sure how to extract skills after training data. Also if you see in the pdf i shared the model has 2 outputs in the last Dense layer

Comment: I did try with 1 in the last Dense layer but output seems to be same as the one i have posted in the question section

Comment: Have you also change "categorical_crossentropy" as "binary_cross_entropy".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236043/discussion-between-hakan-akgun-and-10sha25).

Answer (score 1):

Changed parts (made some intuitive adjustments):

```
model=tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size,100,input_length=max_len))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
```

Instead of pd.get_dummies():

```
y=d['Skill_NotSkill'].replace({"skill":1,"not_skill":0})
```

Result:
[image]